# Actual List cannot be converted to String on method invocation conversion

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, playframework

I am a newbie to play and have started to develop an application to fetch the data from database.

I have the following code in my application:

```
public static Result list() {
    List products = Productslist.getListOfProducts();
    return ok(index.render(products));
}
```

and this gives me the following error:

`Actual List cannot be converted to String on method invocation conversion`
 You can also view my index.scala.html

```
#{extends 'main.html' /}
#{set title:'Cars in the car lot' /}
<h1>Products in Lot</h1>

<table border=1>
<tr>
<td>productname</td>
<td>Quantity</td>
<td>Price</td>
</tr>
#{list items:products, as:'product'}
<tr>
<td>${product.getProductname()}</td>
<td>${product.getQuantity()}</td>
<td>${product.getPrice()}</td>
</tr>
#{/list}
</table>
```

The complete code for Application.java is:

```
package controllers;

import play.*;
import play.mvc.*;
import models.Productslist;
import views.html.*;
import views.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Application extends Controller
{


public static Result list() 
    {
        List products = Productslist.getListOfProducts();
        return ok(index.render(products));
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me find the source of the error?

Comment: Show us also content of your `views/index.scala.html` view

Comment: We need more code. Signature of all the methods.

Comment: I have added the code for index.scala.html above.

Comment: weird! your controller appears to be Play 2 version, but the view (index.scala.html) is still  in 1.2.4 ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look like you used the wrong code for the view. Try this instead

```
@(products: List[Productslist])

@import helper._

@main("Product list") {

    <h1>@product.size() product(s)</h1>

    <ul>
        @for(product <- products) {
            <li>
                @product.name
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
}
```

Use `play clean-all` before running your server

Comment: Thanks a ton Thai Tran. Thanks for your solution it helped me a lot. I just did the same as told by you and it worked. :)

Comment: Ok. Thai Tran i am trapped in other problem in which i am using ajax-jquery in play. THe problem is i cannot use the dyanmic data in button name field.
Here is the code:
<input type="button" value="Add Product" name="@routes.Application.user(product.product_id)" id="but"/>

Comment: Please start another question about your problem

Answer (score 0):

Looks like error is happening on index.render(products) ; where method render is expecting a string but we are passing list. Can you put in the code of method render()

Comment: render() is the inbuilt method of play. I am just passing my list(products) into render() to get used in the index.scala.html